# How to make a field disabled if its value is initialized from state

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I've got a fieldArray where fields are created. I need to do the following: to disable the input if its value is initialized from state(has initial value).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the disabled flag conditionally on whether or not your values have been initialized from state.

Given a boolean `isInitializedFromState`, here is an example:

```
<input disabled={ isInitializedFromState ? "disabled" : false }/>
```

The use of the String `"disabled"` and Boolean `false` is somewhat strange, but this is the way that the `disabled` flag should be set. See this thread for a bit of discussion on it: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/961.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But the real problem is from where I should take 'isInitializedFromState'? How to hook if it was initialized inside the render component of the Field

Comment: Oh, I see. Where is the component getting the values for the state in the first place? From the redux store?

Comment: Sorry for late response, still need the solution. Yes, from the redux store

Comment: @KonstantinKim Can you tell me more about the case when values would be initialized from state vs when they would not be?